# node.js - Can't connect to MYSQL database with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm starting at Node.js and i'm trying to make a simple connection with Sequelize based on its documentation (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/installation/getting-started.html#installation).
Here my db.js file :

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')

const db = new Sequelize('chat','root','root',{
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'

});

db
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });
```

When executing this code, I have no success nor error message, just a message indicating 'String base operators deprecated' but nothing important i think.

I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, remove port number and multiples thread but i'm stucked here...

Comment: Your code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested your code and all seemed to work fine, it connected successfully to the database instance I have running.
You might want to ensure `mysql2` package is installed. Also check that the database `chat` has been created in MySQL workbench, and ensure the password is correct.